# Check Constraint in oracle for yes or no

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

I have to create a table in an art gallery. the table is Art_Object. Among the various attributes, I am having trouble implementing a check constraint for a "Restoration" field where the only values for it can be "Yes" or "No". I have tried various versions of it with double quotations, single quotations, no quotations, making it equal the the field name (ex. Restoration = 'Yes') with no luck. I have also tried CHECK(Restoration IN('Yes', 'No'))... and this has not worked either. I am lost.

Comment: Post your DDL in the question.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Art_Object
(
  column1 datatype null/not null,
  column2 datatype null/not null,
  ...,

  CONSTRAINT check_restoration_yesno
    CHECK (Restoration = 'Yes' OR Restoration = 'No')
);
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that and it didn't work, for some reason it didn't like that I was copying and pasting the statement, I just had to type it out instead. Thank you for your help

Comment: You probably got some other character instead of `'`. This often happens when you copy from MS Word (because MS Word likes to exchange hyphens for typographic hyphens and the Oracle DBMS doesn't like that).